# Can i keep a user in my Mailchimp list after he unsubscribed?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using Mailchimp API in PHP to subscribe users to a Mailchimp list with daily cron job,
I want to keep the users in this list after they unsubscribed (without them getting newsletters) because if they will be deleted from the list i will invite them over and over again with my cron job.
Is there a way to tell Mailchimp through API that i want the list to keep track on those email addresses?

Comment: Sounds like an ethical question to me

Comment: The api provides several ways to get unsubscribed address es

Comment: @scrowler What i am saying is that i do not want to send them an invite everytime. I want to keep track of unsubscribers in order to not invite them again.

Comment: MailChimp divides a subscribe list into three lists: `subscribed`, `unsubscribed` and `cleaned`. So they are not deleted, but still kept. Although you might not be allowed to do so, because if a recipients unsubscribes, he or she usually also revokes your right to store his/her data.

Comment: You should *not* automatically be subscribing users to a mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use v2.0 (or lower) of the API, you will probably encounter trouble keeping users unsubscribed when you sync them over using the BatchSubscribe method. The commenters above are right that MailChimp has multiple statuses, but the current versions of the API don't allow you as much flexibility with them as might be possible within the web application.

[Version 3.0, which is currently in beta](https://github.com/mailchimp/APIv3-examples/wiki), does allow you to update the data of unsubscribed addresses in the system, so you might want to look into upgrading your sync code to use the new version when it comes out.